# How to deal with spaces for boost::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, boost, path, filesystems

I'm trying to take a directory from user input and store it in a path object from the boost library. This worked fine when no spaces were in the directory e.g. C:\Windows\system32\file.exe however when trying to use C:\Program Files\file.exe it doesn't work, the program just exits. I was thinking about taking the input as a string and then operating on it to replace the spaces with escape characters. Is there a better way to do this?

```
boost::filesystem::path path;
std::cout << "Please enter the path for the file you would like to hash:" << std::endl;
std::cout << "E.g. C:\\Program Files\\iTunes\\iTunes.exe" << std::endl;
std::cin >> path;
```

The path is then passed to a function to get hashed. Works fine for a path without spaces but with spaces the program just exits.

```
std::string md5_file(boost::filesystem::path &file)
{
/* Takes a file and returns the md5 hash. */

// Create new hash wrapper
hashwrapper *myWrapper = new md5wrapper();
std::string hash;

// Hash file
try 
{
    hash = myWrapper->getHashFromFile(file.string());
}
catch (hlException &e) 
{
    std::cerr << "Error(" << e.error_number() << "): " << e.error_message() << std::endl;
}

// Clean up
delete myWrapper;
return hash;
}
```

Comment: be more specific what exactly breaks. `filesystem::path` has no issues dealing with spaces.

Comment: try using `getline` to get the entire line the user provided

Comment: I'm gonna second the `getline` suggestion. On top of that, why is `myWrapper` defined as a pointer? It seems like you could get equivalent behavior from that code by simply making a local stack variable. Consigning it to dynamic memory, using naked pointers no less, seems like an easy way to cause bugs down the line when this code is being maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with boost::filesystem::path. Your input has issues. If the path has spaces `cin >> string_variable` will read up to the first white-space separator.

Try to check it:

```
[boost::filesystem::path][1] path;
std::cout << "Please enter the path for the file you would like to hash:" << std::endl;
std::cout << "E.g. C:\\Program Files\\iTunes\\iTunes.exe" << std::endl;
std::cin >> path;
std::cout << path << endl;
```

Output should be something line `C:\\Program`

[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads in entire string with spaces:

```
string str;
getline(cin, s);
path = s;
```

Comment: Instead of using std::cin I've changed it to std::getline(std::cin, string) and now nothing i type works. A weird thing i noticed with the change is now there are two mysterious quotation  marks output to the console.

Comment: @PrimateJunkie sorry for mistake, it's `getline(cin, s);`

Comment: Turns out that getline wasn't working because i was mixing inputs. Had an int input before, just had to clear the input buffer with: std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
Thanks anyway!